# Determining the Longitudes and Latitudes from raw NMEA of unknown format

Tags: gps, latitude-longitude, nmea

I have a data set that has location data of an animal. The data set has very large number of records. I expect to extract latitude and longitude data from the data set that was provided. It might be important to state that these coordinates correspond to locations in Sri Lanka. I found that longitudes in Sri Lanka range from 79.81-81.81 where latitudes range from 9.77-5.94.

```
X,Y,Date,Time
540564.950532,697307.393351,24.07.2012,1:30:19
541154.889569,697570.313356,24.07.2012,5:30:48
421860.001784,869773.695226,25.06.2008,20:01
513559.094669,681860.728185,2006.08.19,4:00:36
```

A real raw data sample can be found from [here][1]

Unfortunately, I am not in a position to ask the sender of the DMS format of x,y coordinates.

What I am after is a mechanism to convert x,y into decimal degree format. The challenge here is that it is unknown the format of the x,y string. it can be DDMMMM.SSSSSS or anything.

Comment: seems we need a "forensic" tag here... are you sure they are not sea animals  - one of the X numbers starts with a 4 which also would be out of the landmass.They don't look like numbers with non-base-10 (like min/sec) to me, the question only is - where is the (0,0) and what's the scaling - if they are not from gps source the coordinates may even have some "grid" as reference - good luck!

Comment: I don't see a hack, only thing would be guessing ... I thought the forensic tag was rather a joke, but it seems that really exists. You can probably try for weeks or months a lot of possibilities and maybe you're lucky, maybe not - that's what I would let my boss decide if it makes sense.

Comment: Look at the min and max values of X and Y. And maybe if they are tagged to indiviual animals, find out the difference of X and Y and the time difference and do that for many points to estimate the maximum "speed"  at which they move - this might give you hints. Reminds me of "hacking" the coordinate system of what later became ms flight simulator more than 30 years ago - turned out the (0,0) was in Champaign, Illinois where the company was based and the coordinates were based on a projection like on a big map of the U.S.- good luck again

Comment: Looks like your coordinates are given in the ED50 system. Converting the first pair of your data (540564.950532,697307.393351) gives 6.30718104380601N, 81.3673548958398E. I've used this site - http://twcc.fr/# but could not find which formula to use. Hope this helps.

Comment: I think it's the ED1950 (UTM) which is the default for the lower window. Just enter your coordinates there and press 'convert' and get the result at the upper window.

Comment: @qwertylicious, try some googling and e.g. [this at gis.stackexchange.com](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122016/transforming-coordinates-between-wgs84-and-utm-ed50-31n-what-am-i-missing) before posting a new question  - you are a big step ahead and should first do what you can to try to get on. If you fail, the question would be where to find a reference for the conversion algorithm... good luck